# code loading in perl <progress-bar>

Tags: perl, progress-bar

this perl code for loading
When running code

```
use Term::ProgressBar::IO;

open my $fh, '<', 'passwords.txt' or die "could not open file n.txt: $!";
my $pb = Term::ProgressBar::IO->new($fh);
my $line_count;
while (<$fh>) {
  $line_count += 1;
  $pb->update();
}
close $fh;
print "total lines $line_count"


C:\Users\USER\Desktop>r.pl
  0% [*                                                                                                                                                               ]total lines 360
```

what is the problem

Comment: your question is not clear to me, I suggest to explain it in greater detail

Answer (score 2):

`Term::ProgressBar::IO` seems incompatible with regular filehandles, and expects an instance of `IO::File` as seen in the [test script](https://metacpan.org/source/MANWAR/Term-ProgressBar-2.21/t/02_term_progressbar_io.t), so you'll want to define `$fh` with

```
my $fh = IO::File->new('passwords.txt', 'r') or die ...;
```

The [docs](https://metacpan.org/pod/Term::ProgressBar::IO) say that this module will work with any seekable filehandle, but it still doesn't work (for me, anyway).

---

The [relevant line during construction](https://metacpan.org/source/MANWAR/Term-ProgressBar-2.21/lib/Term/ProgressBar/IO.pm#L87) is:

```
if (ref($count) and $count->can("seek")) {
```

When `$count` is an `IO::File` type, this condition passes but it fails when `$count` is a regular `GLOB`, even one opened for reading and writing. A `GLOB` will support the `seek` method, but `can("seek")` won't return true until after a method has been called on it.

```
use feature 'say';
open my $fh, '<', 'some-file';
say $fh->can('seek');             # ""
say tell $fh;                     # 0
say $fh->can('seek');             # ""
say eval { $fh->tell };           # 0
say $fh->can('seek');             # 1
```

and this suggests another workaround (one that could be implemented inside `Term::ProgressBar::IO` to address this issue), and that is to make a filehandle method call on the filehandle before you pass it to `Term::ProgressBar::IO`:

```
open my $fh, '<', 'passwords.txt' or die "could not open file n.txt: $!";
eval { $fh->tell };      # endow $fh with methods detectable by UNIVERSAL::can
...
```

Comment: Re "*Term::ProgressBar::IO seems incompatible with regular filehandles, and expects an instance of IO::File*", Regular file handles ARE instances of IO::File

Comment: Are you going to submit a patch, or a failing test?

Comment: Regular file handles behave like instances of IO::File in all cases except when they don't. 
The sample output I have above is from perl v5.24.0. Other versions produce different output, and the workaround I suggested will not work with older perls.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple process bar code, output as below.
[image]

```
   $n = 10;
    for($i=1;$i<=$n;$i++){
            proc_bar($i,$n);
            select(undef, undef, undef, 0.2);
    }

sub proc_bar{
        local $| = 1;
        my $i = $_[0] || return 0;
        my $n = $_[1] || return 0;
        print   "\r [ ".("\032" x int(($i/$n)*50)).(" " x (50 - int(($i/$n)*50)))." ] ";
        printf("%2.1f %%",$i/$n*100);
        local $| = 0;
}
```